# Laravel table relationship to pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm confused on how to get my model setup in laravel with a table that is connected to a pivot table.

Here's the problem

Say I have

```
Locations
    id
    name

area_types
    id
    name

area_type_location (Pivot table)
    id
    location_id
    area_type_id

area_test
    id
    area_type_location_id
    clean
    headCount
```

Relationship between the tables are different areas type belongs to different locations. 
i.e: beach, 25m pools, kids pools, bbq, etc

area_test is connected to the pivot table because the test has to be generated from area that exists, in this case it is area that is registered under different locations. Thus it has to be tested daily, measured, etc.

I understand the structure between area_types and locations for many to many relationship, however I can't get over my head of how do i structure my area_test model? How do I get the data from locations table -> where are my test?

Should I create a model for my pivot table? Is that a good practice in laravel?

Does anyone has the same use case?

I read about eloquent [has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)
 relationship but I understand that it does not mention about getting through pivot table. I don't quite get if my use case is the same.

Thanks

Comment: to what table is related the foreign key in `area_id` in `area_type_location`?

Comment: sorry my bad, was in a hurry previously. edited the question so its clear, its related to the `area_types` table

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally, apparently there are a couple of way to get data from `locations` table to `area_tests`

Tried at tinker and it works,

---

### First Option

I need to create a Pivot model for my Pivot table:

```
class LocationAreaType extends Pivot{

    public function location(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }

    public function areaType(){
        return $this->belongsTo(AreaType::class);
    }

    public function AreaTests(){
        return $this->hasMany(AreaTest::class, 'area_type_location_id');
    }

}
```

I can use `hasManyThrough` relation that I need to create in my Location table

```
public function areaTests()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        AreaTest::class,
        LocationAreaType::class,
        'location_id',
        'area_type_location_id'
    );
}
```

this way I can get the areaTests easily by `$location->areaTests`, My problem was not determining the `area_type_location_id` as foreign. You need to determine this, apparently when I extends pivot and use hasMany laravel does not auto recognise the Foreign key by itself.

---

### Second option

Another way to access it is from the relation table, I can define `withPivot` in the `areaTypes()` relation then access it like this:

`$location->areaType[0]->pivot->areaTests`

Since laravel only recognise foreign key from both tables `location_id` and `area_type_id`, I have to include the `id` of the pivot table to get the AreaTest table data

So in the Location model I have to get the column

```
public function areaTypes()
{
    // Get the ID of the pivot table to get the poolTests table (connected with ID column)
    return $this->belongsToMany(AreaType::class)
        ->using(AreaTypeLocation::class)
        ->withPivot('id');
}
```

Comment: In `class LocationAreaType`, should it be `public function areaTests()` instead of `AreaTests()`?

Comment: How would you write the `location()` relation for`$areaTest->location`?

Comment: @bilogic sorry, i realise that my example was not clear initially. I have edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to create a new model for pivot table.
Just declare in **Location** model below code:

```
  /**
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
   */
  public function area_types()
  {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\AreaType', 'area_type_location', 'location_id', 'area_type_id');

  }
```

and declare below code in **AreaType** model:

```
  /**
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
   */
  public function locations()
  {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location', 'area_type_location', 'area_type_id', 'location_id');

  }
```

every time you need to get for example the locations of an area_type in every controller, you can call the function like this: `$areatype->locations()->get();`

Don't forget to create area_type_location table migration.

Comment: But my question is not about the relationship between `area_types` and `locations`, its about `locations` and `area_test` which is connected to the pivot table

Comment: By declaring relations in above methods, we define the name of the middle table(`area_type_location`) and referral ids(`area_type_id, location_id`) and at the end of the day, the connections to middle table are clear :D

Comment: @SaraVaseei as the OP commented in the past, your answer doesn't explain how to query `area_test`. It doesn't even mention that table.